# numpy genfromtxt not applying missing_values

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I am currently struggling with a really simple problem, but cannot seem to solve it. You can reproduce the issue with the following file and code:

**test.csv**

```
2020081217,28.6
2020081218,24.7
2020081219,-999.0
2020081220,-999.0
2020081221,-999.0
```

**code**

```
data = np.genfromtxt("C:/Users/col/Downloads/test.csv", delimiter=',', missing_values=["-999", "-999.0", -999, -999.0])
print(data)
```

**output**

```
[[ 2.02008122e+09  2.86000000e+01]
 [ 2.02008122e+09  2.47000000e+01]
 [ 2.02008122e+09 -9.99000000e+02]
 [ 2.02008122e+09 -9.99000000e+02]
 [ 2.02008122e+09 -9.99000000e+02]]
```

Why does none of the versions for missing_values catch the -999 in the file and replace them with NaNs or something alike? I feel like this should be simple (and probably already answered somewhere on this website), but I cannot figure it out... Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of missing values.  One is where the value is represent only by the delimiter.  Default fill is `nan`, but we can define a separate fill:

```
In [93]: txt1="""2020081217,28.6
    ...: 2020081218,24.7
    ...: 2020081219,
    ...: 2020081220,
    ...: 2020081221,"""
In [94]: np.genfromtxt(txt1.splitlines(),delimiter=',',encoding=None)
Out[94]: 
array([[2.02008122e+09, 2.86000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09, 2.47000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan]])
In [95]: np.genfromtxt(txt1.splitlines(),delimiter=',',encoding=None,filling_val
    ...: ues=999)
Out[95]: 
array([[2.02008122e+09, 2.86000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09, 2.47000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09, 9.99000000e+02],
       [2.02008122e+09, 9.99000000e+02],
       [2.02008122e+09, 9.99000000e+02]])
```

Your case has a specific string:

```
In [96]: txt="""2020081217,28.6
    ...: 2020081218,24.7
    ...: 2020081219,-999.0
    ...: 2020081220,-999.0
    ...: 2020081221,-999.0"""
```

The other answer suggests using `usemask`, returning a masked_array:

```
In [100]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',encoding=None, missing_values=-999.0, usemask=True)
Out[100]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[2020081217.0, 28.6],
        [2020081218.0, 24.7],
        [2020081219.0, --],
        [2020081220.0, --],
        [2020081221.0, --]],
  mask=[[False, False],
        [False, False],
        [False,  True],
        [False,  True],
        [False,  True]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

Looking at the code, I deduce that it's doing a string match, rather than a numeric one.  It can also take one value per column  (I don't think it does a per-row test):

```
In [106]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',encoding=None, 
    missing_values=['2020081217','-999.0'], usemask=True, dtype=None)
Out[106]: 
masked_array(data=[(--, 28.6), (2020081218, 24.7), (2020081219, --),
                   (2020081220, --), (2020081221, --)],
             mask=[( True, False), (False, False), (False,  True),
                   (False,  True), (False,  True)],
       fill_value=(999999, 1.e+20),
            dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

Here I gave it `dtype=None`, so it returned a structured array.

`missing_values` can also be dict, but I haven't figured out what it expects.

I haven't figured out how to make it replace the missing values with something (such as from the `filling_values`).

You do the replace after load

```
In [110]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',encoding=None)
In [111]: data
Out[111]: 
array([[ 2.02008122e+09,  2.86000000e+01],
       [ 2.02008122e+09,  2.47000000e+01],
       [ 2.02008122e+09, -9.99000000e+02],
       [ 2.02008122e+09, -9.99000000e+02],
       [ 2.02008122e+09, -9.99000000e+02]])

In [114]: data[data==-999] = np.nan
In [115]: data
Out[115]: 
array([[2.02008122e+09, 2.86000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09, 2.47000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan]])
```

It looks like `genfromtxt` constructs a `converters` from the missing and filling values, but I haven't followed the details.  Here's a way of using our converter

```
In [138]: converters={1:lambda x: np.nan if x=='-999.0' else float(x)}
In [139]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',encoding=None, 
    converters=converters)
In [140]: data
Out[140]: 
array([[2.02008122e+09, 2.86000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09, 2.47000000e+01],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan],
       [2.02008122e+09,            nan]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using the post-load replacement which I also did before already since it is the fastest option. Weird that this is not better documented.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `usemask=True`.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=',', usemask=True, missing_values=-999.0)
```

Fill-in with NANs.

```
data = data.filled(np.nan)
```

Check for NANs.

```
np.isnan(data)
```

Output.

```
array([[False, False],
   [False, False],
   [False,  True],
   [False,  True],
   [False,  True]])
```

Comment: So this `data` is a `masked_array`, and you are using `np.ma` methods to changed the masked values to `nan`.