# numpy genfromtxt - how to detect bad int input values

Tags: numpy, genfromtxt, dtype

Here is a trivial example of a bad `int` value to `numpy.genfromtxt`. For some reason, I can't detect this bad value, as it's showing up as a valid int of -1.

```
>>> bad = '''a,b
0,BAD
1,2
3,4'''.splitlines()
```

My input here has 2 columns of ints, named a and b. b has a bad value, where we have a string "BAD" instead of an integer. However, when I call `genfromtxt`, I cannot detect this bad value.

```
>>> out = np.genfromtxt(bad, delimiter=',', dtype=(numpy.dtype('int64'), numpy.dtype('int64')), names=True, usemask=True, usecols=tuple('ab'))
>>> out

masked_array(data=[(0, -1), (1, 2), (3, 4)],
         mask=[(False, False), (False, False), (False, False)],
   fill_value=(999999, 999999),
        dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8')])

>>> out['b'].data
array([-1,  2,  4])
```

I print out the column 'b' from my output, and I'm shocked to see that it has a -1 where the string "BAD" is supposed to be. The user has no idea that there was bad input. In fact, if you only look at the output, this is totally indistinguishable from the following input

```
>>> bad2 = '''a,b
0,-1
1,2
3,4'''.splitlines()
```

I feel like I must be using genfromtxt wrong. How is it possible that it can't detect bad input?

Comment: It would be polite if you referenced the work we already did.  The only difference here is that you specify `int` dtype.  While it's not documented it appears that `genfromtxt` assigns a `-1` for missing and bad values (ones where `int(str)` returns an error).  The float counterpart is `nan`.  Have you looked into using `converters`?

Comment: Up to now I've just been using the docs of `np.genfromtxt`, but they also reference a page with more details, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html.  It has a short table of default `fill_values`, including the `-1` for `int` dtype.  It also gives more `converters` examples.

Comment: Same issue but with `float` dtype: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65298097/numpy-genfromtxt-missing-data-vs-bad-data

Answer (score 0):

I found in `np.lib._iotools` a function

```
def _loose_call(self, value):
    try:
        return self.func(value)
    except ValueError:
        return self.default
```

When `genfromtxt` is processing a line it does

```
if loose:
    rows = list(
        zip(*[[conv._loose_call(_r) for _r in map(itemgetter(i), rows)]
              for (i, conv) in enumerate(converters)]))
```

where `loose` is an input parameter.  So in the case of `int` converter it tries

```
int(astring)
```

and if that produces a `ValueError` it returns the default value (e.g. `-1`) instead of raising an error.  Similarly for `float` and `np.nan`.

The `usemask` parameter is applied in:

```
        if usemask:
            append_to_masks(tuple([v.strip() in m
                                   for (v, m) in zip(values,
                                                     missing_values)]))
```

Define 2 converters to give more information on what's processed:

```
def myint(astr):
    try:
        v = int(astr)
    except ValueError:
        print('err',astr)
        v = '-999'
    return v

def myfloat(astr):
    try:
        v = float(astr)
    except ValueError:
        print('err',astr)
        v = '-inf'
    return v
```

A sample text:

```
txt='''1,2
3,nan
,foo
bar,
'''.splitlines()
```

And using the converters:

```
In [242]: np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',', converters={0:myint, 1:myfloat})
err b''
err b'bar'
err b'foo'
err b''
Out[242]: 
array([(   1,   2.), (   3,  nan), (-999, -inf), (-999, -inf)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

And to see what `usemask` does:

```
In [243]: np.genfromtxt(txt, delimiter=',', converters={0:myint, 1:myfloat}, usemask=True)
err b''
err b'bar'
err b'foo'
err b''
Out[243]: 
masked_array(data=[(1, 2.0), (3, nan), (--, -inf), (-999, --)],
             mask=[(False, False), (False, False), ( True, False),
                   (False,  True)],
       fill_value=(999999, 1.e+20),
            dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

A missing value is a '' string, and `int('')` produces a ValueError just as `int('bad')` does.  So for the converter, default or my custom ones, a missing value is the same as bad one.  Your converter could make a distinction.  But only 'missing' set the the `mask`.